# How to notify screen that floating action button in bottom navigation bar is pressed in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-animation

I am quite new to flutter. I have a bottom navigation bar with a floating action button on it. When the floating action button is pressed I want an animation to be triggered on the screen. How can I notify the screen that the FAB Button was pressed?
Best regards!

Comment: You need to add the action you want in the onPressed from button. Or wrap your Widget with a InkWell or GestureDetector and add the action to the onTap

Comment: Thanks. That ist clear. It is more the bottom nav bar and the floating action button are not in the same class. So I need to notify the widget of the screen somehow if the button in the navbar was pressed. Is that understandable?